# Retrieve the string from ctypes's c_char_p

Tags: python, ctypes

In Python, I have a ctypes.c_char_p's string, 'Hello, world'. It seems that python automatically encodes it to a number (see below from my ipython console). How can I retrieve the string, namely,  'Hello, world', from the ctypes.c_char_p object?

```
In [45]: from ctypes import c_char_p

In [46]: c_char_p("Hello, World")
Out[46]: c_char_p(4508383228)
```

Comment: All simple ctypes data types have a `value` attribute that returns a native Python object, such as an `int` or `str`, depending on the data type.

Comment: @eryksun: You ought to post that as an answer.

Comment: @icktoofay, I think it's [already explained clearly](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes-fundamental-data-types-2). Feel free to post an answer if you want.

Comment: zell, why do you suppose the repr  displays the memory address (the number) instead of the string's `value`? Notice in the Python 2 [tutorial examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) that the repr actually shows the string. That tells me the example was evaluated on a Windows box. In Python 3 we no longer make an exception for the repr on Windows, since it relied on `IsBadStringPtr`, a [bogus](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563) Winows API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, although perhaps not as explicitly as some might require, the `.value` attribute converts from `ctypes.c_char_p` to a Python string.

This code round trips a Python string to a `ctypes.c_char_p` and then back to a Python string:

```
>>> p = c_char_p("Hello, World")
>>> p
c_char_p(140323010068388)
>>> type(p)
<class 'ctypes.c_char_p'>
>>> s = p.value
>>> s
'Hello, World'
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
```